# remote OS detection in python

Tags: python-3.x, nmap, os-detection

I want to implement an OS detection using python (like nmap), I find [python-nmap-0.3.4.tar.gz](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/) library, but it didn't provide Operating system in response!
How can I change it to achieve my goal.

EDIT:
in the [site](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/) sample:

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
>>> nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')
>>> print(nm.csv())
host;protocol;port;name;state;product;extrainfo;reason;version;conf
127.0.0.1;tcp;22;ssh;open;OpenSSH;protocol 2.0;syn-ack;5.9p1 Debian 5ubuntu1;10
127.0.0.1;tcp;25;smtp;open;Exim smtpd;;syn-ack;4.76;10
127.0.0.1;tcp;53;domain;open;dnsmasq;;syn-ack;2.59;10
127.0.0.1;tcp;80;http;open;Apache httpd;(Ubuntu);syn-ack;2.2.22;10
127.0.0.1;tcp;111;rpcbind;open;;;syn-ack;;10
127.0.0.1;tcp;139;netbios-ssn;open;Samba smbd;workgroup: WORKGROUP;syn-ack;3.X;10
127.0.0.1;tcp;443;;open;;;syn-ack;;
```

it find OS , but when I run my own it didn't show any os.
is there any function to find remote OS?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5):

Try with -O option

```
nm.scan('scanme.nmap.org', arguments='-O')
```

The problem is the information will not appear if you do

```
print(nm.csv())
```

So you have to do a loop

```
nm.scan("127.0.0.1", arguments="-O")
if 'osclass' in nm['127.0.0.1']:
    for osclass in nm['127.0.0.1']['osclass']:
        print('OsClass.type : {0}'.format(osclass['type']))
        print('OsClass.vendor : {0}'.format(osclass['vendor']))
        print('OsClass.osfamily : {0}'.format(osclass['osfamily']))
        print('OsClass.osgen : {0}'.format(osclass['osgen']))
        print('OsClass.accuracy : {0}'.format(osclass['accuracy']))
        print('')
```

More info https://bitbucket.org/xael/python-nmap/src/391178ab25a20d7b5edbca51e187f93dc1c16ad2/example.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

PS: you need python 3.x, i don't think that it's works with Python 2.x

EDIT
Of course, you can access directly by

```
print nm['127.0.0.1']['osclass']
```

Or

```
print nm['127.0.0.1']['osclass']['vendor']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the OS name then you can do this:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
machine = nm.scan('<hostIP>', arguments='-O')
print(machine['scan']['<hostIP>']['osmatch'][0]['osclass'][0]['osfamily'])
```

This will provide OS Name [Ex: 'Linux']